# At least one integer equal to one in creating a uniform random distribution

Tags: r, random

I have created a string of integers taking the value 0 or 1 with a uniform random distribution.

```
s <- floor(runif(7, min=0, max=2))
```

Because it is random, it could be that all values of the vector s are 0.

But I would like at least one of the integers to take the value 1.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Comment: Maybe `sample(c(1, floor(runif(6, 0, 2))))`?

Comment: Why not just make a `rbinom(7, size = 1, prob = 0.5)` and adjust `prob`?

Comment: thanks! Both solutions work.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  or just `c(1,floor(runif(6,0,2))`

Comment: @CarlWitthoft but that will always place 1 at the beginning of the string. Believe me it was my first thought :)

Comment: @DavidArenburg good point;  The OP didn't say the `1` had to be in a random position (weasel-word excuse)